# TensorFlow CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to build a large CNN in TensorFlow, and intend to run it on a multi-GPU system. I've adopted a "tower" system and split batches for both GPUs, while keeping the variables and other computations on the CPU. My system has 32GB of memory, but when I run my code I get the error:

```
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:924] failed to alloc 17179869184 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
W ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.h:195] could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 17179869184
Killed
```

I've seen that the code works (though very very slowly) if I hide CUDA devices to TensorFlow, and thus it doesn't use cudaMallocHost()...

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 13):

There are some options:

1- reduce your batch size

2- use memory growing:

```
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
session = tf.Session(config=config, ...)
```

3- don't allocate whole of your GPU memory(only 90%):

```
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.9
session = tf.Session(config=config, ...)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but neither solutions worked, because they only affect GPU memory... my error is about host memory...

Comment: I further discovered that my error occurs immediately after `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())`

Comment: if your last layer is a Fully Connected layer, then decrease the filter number (channels) of that, at least try it

Comment: Turns out that my model was incorrect and was getting a huge number of inputs on the first fully-connected layer, increasing the network space far too much. But thanks for the tips though!

Answer (score 0):

reduce the batch_size in your code to 100 then it'll work